# How to make a SPARQL query return data in HTML table format?

Tags: html, jsp, sparql, jena

I have a problem here, it looks easy but because I am not really familiar with Sparal queries I could not find a solution for it.

Let me explain my problem. I want to show the result of a SPARQL quer in an HTML table.
I have created my query and it's successfully executed but I don't know how to display the result as an HTML table on a web page.

For example, I want one cell to contain a name and another cell to show all information or description about the people who have that name...this name is taken from my ontology. I wonder if it's possible. If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: It is possible but you have to tell us what tools/libraries you're using to execute the query and what output format is currently used.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i use eclipse and Jena TDB

Answer (score 3):

Jena does not, by default, offer a way to output query results as HTML. It is, however, possible to make it produce XML. You'll need a [`ResultSetFormatter`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html). Here's an example:

```
Dataset ds = TDBFactory.createDataset(dbDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
Model model = ds.getDefaultModel();
String query = "SELECT * WHERE {?subject ?predicate ?object .}";
execution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model.getUnionGraph());
ResultSet results = execution.execSelect();
resultString = ResultSetFormatter.asXMLString(results);
```

(exception catching omitted for clarity)

The XML you'll get this way will have a very simple form. Here's an example for the query I used above:

```
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="subject"/>
    <variable name="predicate"/>
    <variable name="object"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="subject">
        <uri>http://blahblahblah</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="predicate">
        <uri>http://foobar</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="object">
        <uri>http://fizzbuzz</uri>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="subject">
        <uri>http://yadayada</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="predicate">
        <uri>http://example</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="object">
        <literal>This is a literal, expect them to pop up here and there too</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <!-- and the results continue like this -->
  </results>
</sparql>
```

Getting from here to an HTML table is a matter of applying an XSL transformation. Reading the data with XPath or an XML parser and passing it to a JSP will also be easy.

Another option is to use the `ResultSetFormatter` to return a `Model` and use the [iterators provided by Jena](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Navigating a Model) to construct a table.